# Why can't we have tag scores unified?

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, tag-score

Recently I had scored 1 point (1 upvote, 10 reputation points) for my answer in the [digital-logic] tag on Stack Overflow, but I was dismayed to find out that this score was not reflected in the [digital-logic] tag of the Electrical Stack Exchange. The reason I'm bringing this to the notice of the Stack Exchange community is that I'd like to earn a badge in the topic [digital-logic], but this becomes more difficult as the questions with this tag tend to be in both Electrical Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow. This makes it needlessly hard to earn the badge. My request is that tag badge score should be unified. I'm certain that other users would also face the same problem as many questions with the same tag would be on different Stack Exchange sites.

**It would be even better if reputation points in common tags would go to all the Stack Exchange accounts with those tags.**

I request this to happen on a retrospective basis.

For example, if I earn 10 reputation points on the [digital-logic] tag in Stack Overflow, then 10 reputation points should also be awarded for my Electrical Stack Exchange account, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why can't we have tag scores unified?

Because tags don't necessary mean the same thing on different sites. Being an expert in, say, [salt](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/salt) (the culinary sort) doesn't mean you're an expert in [salt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/salt) (the cryptographic sort).

Even if two sites *do* have the same topic, it might be that the tag is written differently, e.g. [big-data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/big-data) vs. [bigdata](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bigdata).

There's no way to have a system determine whether two equally/similarly named tags are identical enough to be considered 'one tag split over multiple sites', so I fear your proposal is doomed to fail.

Yes, it might be harder this way to earn a tag badge, but you can look at it from the positive side: you now have the opportunity to earn *two* badges with the same name. How cool is that?

Comment: @ShashankVM I would argue that it being hard to earn a badge, which doesn't really do anything (until you get the dupe-hammer at gold level), *isn't* a real problem. Certainly not enough of one to justify building out the taxonomy mapping tags across this whole network.

Comment: @ShashankVM what "benefit"? The only outcome beyond flair is that they get to dupehammer on sites they may never have visited before, which doesn't seem ideal. And SO alone has 1,724 *pages* of tags (36 tags per page means ~60k tags, and even the newest sites have 7-8 pages in their first few months) and there are ~180 sites in the network, so I'm guessing... quite hard.

Comment: Because of my [tag:discussion], [tag:support] and [tag:feature-request] gold badges here on Meta.SE, I'd be able to dupehammer 90% of the questions on all meta sites in the network o_O

Comment: @ShashankVM If I have a dupehammer earned on one site, I am fairly sure I'd be well equipped to use it. After all, I've devoted a lot of time into that site and *those questions*. I'd be familiar with a lot of common questions and I'd be able to more accurately identify which new questions link to which older questions. But that expertise doesn't transitively relate to any other site. If I have a gold badge on SO, I don't necessarily know the body of questions on SE that relate to the same topic. And vice versa. I can hardly make accurate dupe judgements.